# How can I define an expiry date to a scheduled task using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, task, scheduling

Is there a way I can schedule a task using PowerShell that for 30 days runs on daily basis every 15 mins, and after those 30 days it expires?

I have done the scheduling but I am unable to find anything where we can set an expiry date using `New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet`.

Code:

```
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 9am
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId $user -RunLevel Highest -LogonType ServiceAccount
$task = Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'KView' -Description 'Kview setup for monitoring' -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Principal $principal
#$task.Triggers.StartBoundary = $date
#$task.Triggers.EndBoundary = $date.AddDays(30)
$task.Triggers.Repetition.Duration = 'P1D'
$task.Triggers.Repetition.Interval = 'PT15M'
$task | Set-ScheduledTask -User $user -Password $password
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example of the code that will set the expiry for you, just change the `TargetTask` name and `EndBoundary` value.

Notice that Triggers are arrays. This scheduled task only has one trigger, so we leave it as `$Task.Triggers[0]`.

```
# Fetch the scheduled task object
$Task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Test"

# Set the date and time it will expire
$Task.Triggers[0].EndBoundary = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")

$Task | Set-ScheduledTask
```

Comment: Your answer, the last line in particular, help me solve this. I was modifing setting, but did not apply them until I piped task object to `Set-ScheduledTask`. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to use the same approach specified by @Otter in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68535661/3095259 when creating a new scheduled task. In this case, rather than extracting a scheduled task from the system, you create a new task, as in the example below.

```
$TaskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" -Argument "-File $ScriptPath"
$TaskTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At $Start -RepetitionInterval $Interval
$TaskTrigger.EndBoundary = $EndDateTime
$TaskPrincipal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -Id $User -UserId $User -LogonType Password -RunLevel Limited
$TaskSetting = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -Compatibility Win8
$Task = New-ScheduledTask -Description $Description -Action $TaskAction -Principal $TaskPrincipal -Trigger $TaskTrigger -Settings $TaskSetting
$Task | Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $Name -TaskPath $TaskPath -User $User -Password $Password | Out-Null
```